# xamarin.android app rejected from play store due to Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms android application, I am using xamarin.essentials PhoneDialer to make call from app.
I added two permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Everything works. But where I got problems is when I try to upload the app to play store.My app get rejected.

I got this message from play store

*Issue: Violation of Permissions policy After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
You declared {Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)} as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
Please either:*

> Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
>   Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality

*Default handler capability for {Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)} was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised Permissions Declaration Form and/or add default handler capability to your app.*

When I uploaded the APK, play console asked a Permissions Declaration Form and I selected DEFAULT PHONE HANDlER checkbox. In my app I only make call through phones dialer. What will be the solution to this? How can I make the app to be accepted by play store? Any help is appreicated.

Comment: If you are not publishing a replacement for the "Default Phone handler", do not state that it is.... (I'm assuming all you are doing to launching that phone's dialer with a predetermined phone number from your app, that is not replacing the phone's dialer)

Comment: @SushiHangover I have a pre determined number in my app and when user taps, it will open in dialer. So what should I do now to resolve this?

Comment: @SushiHangover So no need to tick any of the checkboxes in Permissions Declaration Form?

Comment: No, you do not need to check the "Default Phone handler" exception

Answer (score 1):

I know this is bit late. But for anyone who may have this issue in future.

We had **exactly** the same issues, what we did was remove every drafts, replace every track (alpha, beta and production etc) where the non-compliant version is active.

Also ensure other information like Privacy Policy links etc are accurate in Store Listing.